# Nodes from Japan showing up as from Netherlands?

Tags: relays

How does Tor determine what country a node is based in? For ex, tracerouting this current relay ip `45.32.55.55` shows it is from Japan, but Tor tags it as being from the [Netherlands](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/FE516805FE0F9EB270E0697E9BB71F4F72788003)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IP geolocation is generally not an exact science, and similar anomalies have been discussed before: [Why does hard coded node 'Faravahar' have a different geolocation (USA) than registrar (Mauritius)?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/368/why-does-hard-coded-node-faravahar-have-a-different-geolocation-usa-than-reg)

For example, [this site](https://www.iplocation.net/) (and others like it) check several different databases, and give several different results for the IP address you're looking at (including both Japan and the Netherlands, but also France).